# Wordpress - Unexpected Token Errors...Expected LBRACE and Expected IDENT Errors

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a Twenty-Sixteen child theme in Wordpress.  But I'm getting 25 errors...mostly Unexpected Token errors, but some Expected LBRACE and Expected IDENT errors.  I have no idea what these mean.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbMdO.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lVjj.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLwxL.jpg

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentysixteen-style' for the Twenty Sixteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove the above lines from style.css and add it into functions.php

Comment: Thank you very much, Tamil!  That fixed everything.